# http post is inconsistently not invoked

Tags: angular, spring

I am currently working on a logout implementation for angular (with a spring backend). Logout is done via a http post to /auth/logout, the endpoint expires auth-token and refresh-token httponly cookies.

app.component (updated after comments):

```
logout(): void {
        console.log("logout() before calling logoutTest()")
        //this.storageService.clean()
        this.authService.logoutTest().pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                console.log("finally..");
            })
        )
            .subscribe({
                error: (err) => {
                    console.log("error in logout()")
                    console.log(err);
                },
                next: () => {
                  console.log("next..")
                },
                complete: () => {
                    console.log("complete..")
                    console.log("clean session storage")
                    this.storageService.clean()
                }
            });
        console.log("logout() after logoutTest() call")
    }
```

auth.service logoutTest()

```
  logoutTest() {
        return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'logout', {}, httpOptions)
    }
```

It generally works, however I am experiencing a weird issue: sometimes (like 1/10) the session storage which contains the user is not cleared. It should be done when the post to the backend was successful.

Example log error case:

```
logout() before calling logoutTest()
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 logout() after logoutTest() call
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/web/
```

Example log success case (updated after comments):

```
logout() before calling logoutTest()
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 logout() after logoutTest() call
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 next..
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 complete..
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 clean session storage
main.337e8f596a9ab9f9.js:1 finally..
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/web/
```

What I do not understand is that also in the error case I can see in the chrome dev-tools that the cookies are expired, so the post call must have happened?

If I uncomment `//this.storageService.clean()` it works consistently.

I'm new to angular, so maybe this is some weird timing issue?

Update:
I noticed that when it happens, the dev-console shows:

```
​ XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/logout".
```

Comment: in case of error, you are not even getting anything, can you use `error: (err) => {` in your error block to see if if something gets printed?

Comment: use finally()/complete() instead of next(). This will be called once the subscribe is complete

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. I updated the code. Unfortunately it still happens. In the "error" case nothing gets logged, not even the finally log. It just seems to skip the whole call.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a log in the "logoutTest" methode, before the return. You will see, if it is returned something.

If not, it could a wrong authService called.

Can you check if your authService is correctly imported ? Check your constructor / component providers ?

Comment: I think the authService is correctly imported since it all works most of the time. But if needed I can add the implementation. I just enabled "LogXmlHttpRequests" in the chrome dev-tools and now see this when the error happens: `XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/logout".`

Comment: Maybe the problem come from  `this.storageService.clean()` which reload the page. If it is the case, it reloads the page before the api call is trigger.